# ViewModel of Partial View Not Binding to that of main ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a trouble with binding a value of partial view model to main view model. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any hint would be helpful.

ViewModels

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int ParentName { get; set; }

    public ChildViewModel childViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public bool HasChild { get; set; }
}
```

Razor view

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ChildViewPartial", Model.childViewModel)
```

Child Partial View

```
@model ChildViewModel

    <input asp-for="@Model.HasChild"
           asp-error-class="error"
           class="input"
           id="HasChild"
           autocomplete="off"
           type="checkbox"
           value="@true">

    <label class="checkboxes" for="HasChild">
        Do you have child?
    </label>
```

Now problem what I am facing is value of HasChild is always false in a post action.

If I include the code of child view model in a main view and use

```
asp-for="@Model.ChildViewModel.HasChild"
```

for check box then it works.

Comment: Could you post full main view and main view action pls?

Answer (score 0):

you can change view model

```
public class ParentViewModel:ChildViewModel
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int ParentName { get; set; }
  
}
```

in this case child model could be the same

or just add HasChild to Parent. Why not?

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int ParentName { get; set; }

    public bool HasChild { get; set; }
}
```

in this case your child view model needs to be changed to parent

```
@model ParentViewModel

    <input asp-for="HasChild"
    ....
```

but in both cases your main view should be the same like this, it is very important

```
<partial name="_ChildViewPartial" />
```